# Cannot locate stig -JSON dmg file for iOS

Tags: ios, json

I know there are already questions on stackoverflow about which framework to use.  I have seen more developers suggesting JSON framework on following link "https://github.com/stig/json-framework/" but a zip file downloaded from above URl contains various things but no dmg file. All tutorial's using this framework mention to add "JSON" (from dmg file) folder to Classes but I am not able to locate it. Am I missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use it in projects, just include everything in the Classes folder :)

(there might be a more 'official' method but I quite like having all the source in my project if I ever need to debug anything).

Why were you expecting a dmg file - can you link to one of the tutorials you mention?

Comment: Thanks for your response deanWombourne. one of the link is http://blog.zachwaugh.com/post/309924609/how-to-use-json-in-cocoaobjective-c. just wanted to add something that is only required.

Comment: Ah - that tutorial says version 2.2.1 is the latest version and the downloads start and 2.3.x going up to 3! I don't use the downloads link - I prefer to clone it in git so that's why I've never run into the problem that you have.

Comment: And taking a look at the download (2.3.2 iphone https://github.com/downloads/stig/json-framework/JSON%20v2.3.2%20(iPhone).zip) I get a folder called Classes - that's the one you want to copy into your project and include everything inside it :)

Comment: thanks a lot  deanWombourne. Next time I will remember your instructions. I got the classes folder. Again thanks for your time.

Comment: The download folder contain classes folder. If I import the folder into my project how can I import the JSON.h file ?

Comment: The classes folder contains SBJson.h .Why are you expecting the file to be called JSON.h?